# Laravel 8 is not loading css and js

Tags: php, css, laravel, laravel-8

I have css under **App/resources/css** by default

when I open Login and Register page css is not loading. This is default css and js link on my **app.blade.php**

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

I did this

```
<link href="{{ URL::asset('assets/css/a.css') }}"  rel="stylesheet">
```

and also tried

```
<script src="{{ asset('resources/js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<link href="{{ asset('resources/css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

What shall I do to make it work.??

Comment: `resources` folder data you cannot access by `asset()`  read this https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix

Comment: You need to put it on `/public` directory, not `/resources` directory. Ex : `/public/css/app.css` then you can access `{{ asset('css/app.css') }}`

Comment: @sta:: I tried moving the css and js to public folder but nothing changes. I would be grateful If u provide ma a solution to access a css and js file. Thank You

Comment: @KamleshPaul- Is there any other way so that I can put css and js files in public folder and access it? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

Move all your CSS and JavaScript to the public folder so that your structure becomes something like

```
public/
    |--- css/
    |---js/
```

Now to use your CSS and JavaScript from your new location do something like

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/app.js') }}" defer></script>
<link href="{{ asset('css/app.css') }}" rel="stylesheet">
```

This works because the `asset()` blade helper already looks from the public directory so you start your CSS and JavaScript URL construction from that point on

Comment: Shouldn't this happen automatically though? When you install the ui and auth, why doesn't it also move the css and js to /public?

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend to always use the `mix` helper in Blade like this

```html
<script src="{{ mix('/js/app.js') }}"></script>
```

as it additionally properly takes care of [versioned assets](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/mix#versioning-and-cache-busting). Please make sure you either ran `npm run dev` or `npm run prod` (see [Compiling assets](http://%3Cscript%20src=%22%7B%7B%20asset(%27js/app.js%27)%20%7D%7D%22%20defer%3E%3C/script%3E%20%3Clink%20href=%22%7B%7B%20asset(%27css/app.css%27)%20%7D%7D%22%20rel=%22stylesheet%22%3E)) to generate the `public/css/app.css` and `public/js/app.js` files from the ones located in `resources`.

Comment: Hi, I am running into similar problem while deploying on Vercel. I have done npm run prod and I can see both css and js files in the public folder. I have deployed it but on the vercel link it shows 404 on both files. Any idea?